# Tensorflow, i-th element min-max clamping

Tags: tensorflow

Given a tensor of rank 1 eg. `p = [x y z w]`, how can I "min-max clamp" within the provided boundaries: `max = [1 10 5 3]` and `min = [-1 -10 -5 -3]` such that the i-th element in `p` is always within the boundaries defined by min<sub>i</sub> and max<sub>i</sub>

Extra: Would it be possible to do this for ranks > 1?

Comment: tldr; I want to try and implement GBestPSO with boundary clamping. So far I can do the update and evaluate functions, but I can not seem to figure out how to do boundary clamping.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution adequate. See the documentation for [tf.minimum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/minimum) and [tf.maximum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/maximum). Solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf

p = tf.Variable([-1, 1, 3, 7])

clamp_min = tf.Variable([1, 1, 1, 1])
clamp_max = tf.Variable([5, 5, 5, 5])

p = tf.minimum(p, clamp_max)
p = tf.maximum(p, clamp_min)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(p))
```

Produces:

```
[1 1 3 5]
```

Comment: If users like, I could post a link to my Tensorflow implementation of GBestPSO?